# Bluetooth Headphones with the Pico W

Tags: pi-pico, pi-pico-w

I have a Pi Pico W, and I wanted to do a project where I connect an SD card to the Pico, and it'll play the audio on my headphones. I know that the Pico W has Bluetooth support, but I can't find any way to connect headphones to it.

Thank you for your time,
Mason